# How to aapend data efficiently into pandas dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the data from Python script and storing that into a list and then creating a dataframe out of it.

But it create different Datafarme's for individual items in for loop, how to avoid that and create a single dataFrame.

**Code:**

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
import getpass
import ssl
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect
from pyVmomi import vim
from ssl import CERT_NONE, PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, SSLContext
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)

s = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
s.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
userid = input("please enter your wbi userid (ex. abx@example.com):")
p = getpass.getpass("password:")
vcenter = ["vcenter-oracle.com","vcente.simplivity.com"]
for instance in vcenter:
    try:
        c = SmartConnect(host=instance, user=userid, pwd=p, sslContext=s)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
    content = c.content
    obj_ds = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder,[vim.Datastore],True)
# Lists
    a_list = []
    b_list = []
    c_list = []
    d_list = []
    
# for loop
    for z in obj_ds.view:
        a_list.append(instance)
        b_list.append(z)
        c_list.append(int(z.summary.capacity/(1024*1024*1024)))
        d_list.append(int(z.summary.freeSpace/(1024*1024*1024)))

#dataframe

    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a_list, 'B': b_list, 'C': c_list, 'D': d_list})
```

I also tried as below for for loop section but result are same:

```
    raw_data = []
    for z in obj_ds.view:
        vc_data = instance, z, int(z.summary.capacity/(1024*1024*1024)) ,int(z.summary.freeSpace/(1024*1024*1024))
        raw_data.append(vc_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['Vcenter', 'DS', 'TDS', 'FDS'])
    print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                    A                              B      C     D
0   vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-357'    439   430
1   vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-311'    439   430
2   vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-306'    439   430
3   vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-262'  20480  7030
4   vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-356'    439   430
5   vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-465'     52    46
6   vcenter-oracle.com   'vim.Datastore:datastore-94'   5836  1850
7   vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-122'  11646  3592
8   vcenter-oracle.com   'vim.Datastore:datastore-89'     52    46
9   vcenter-oracle.com   'vim.Datastore:datastore-83'     52    46
10  vcenter-oracle.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-149'     52    46
                       A                                 B     C     D
0  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-143230'  1945   501
1  vcenter.simplivity.com   'vim.Datastore:datastore-52354'  5120  2096
2  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-142927'   274   271
3  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-143231'  2048   987
4  vcenter.simplivity.com     'vim.Datastore:datastore-878'   553   549
5  vcenter.simplivity.com     'vim.Datastore:datastore-877'   553   552
6  vcenter.simplivity.com   'vim.Datastore:datastore-74327'  1500   949
7  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-142929'   274   271
8  vcenter.simplivity.com     'vim.Datastore:datastore-708'  4677  1933
```

**Expected:**

```
                    A                                   B      C     D
0   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-357'    439   430
1   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-311'    439   430
2   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-306'    439   430
3   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-262'  20480  7030
4   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-356'    439   430
5   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-465'     52    46
6   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-94'   5836  1850
7   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-122'  11646  3592
8   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-89'     52    46
9   vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-83'     52    46
10  vcenter-oracle.com      'vim.Datastore:datastore-149'     52    46
11  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-143230'  1945   501
12  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-52354'  5120  2096
13  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-142927'   274   271
14  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-143231'  2048   987
15  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-878'   553   549
16  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-877'   553   552
17  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-74327'  1500   949
18  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-142929'   274   271
19  vcenter.simplivity.com  'vim.Datastore:datastore-708'  4677  1933
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little tweak needs to be done as mentioned in the previous answer that you need to declare list construct before the first loop, as after every instance change, `raw_data` getting reinitialize to an empty list.

try below, it should work for you.

```
s = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
s.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
userid = input("please enter your wbi userid (ex. abx@example.com):")
p = getpass.getpass("password:")
vcenter = ["vcenter-oracle.com","vcente.simplivity.com"]
# Place your list construct here
raw_data = []
# First loop
for instance in vcenter:
    try:
        c = SmartConnect(host=instance, user=userid, pwd=p, sslContext=s)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
    content = c.content
    obj_ds = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder,[vim.Datastore],True)
    # Second loop
    for z in obj_ds.view:
        vc_data = instance, z, int(z.summary.capacity/(1024*1024*1024)) ,int(z.summary.freeSpace/(1024*1024*1024))
        raw_data.append(vc_data)

 # Create the DataFrame and process the columns.
 # Keep the DataFrame outside the for loop.
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['Vcenter', 'DS', 'TDS', 'FDS'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 already, this works well.

Answer (score 1):

```
# new df to concat every instance
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for instance in vcenter:
    try:
        c = SmartConnect(host=instance, user=userid, pwd=p, sslContext=s)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
    content = c.content
    obj_ds = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder,[vim.Datastore],True)
# Lists
    a_list = []
    b_list = []
    c_list = []
    d_list = []
    
# for loop
    for z in obj_ds.view:
        a_list.append(instance)
        b_list.append(z)
        c_list.append(int(z.summary.capacity/(1024*1024*1024)))
        d_list.append(int(z.summary.freeSpace/(1024*1024*1024)))

#dataframe

    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a_list, 'B': b_list, 'C': c_list, 'D': d_list})
    # append in final_df
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df])

# reset index
final_df = final_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(final_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 already, this is also good as another alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are two for loops in your code, and you initialize pandas dataframe inside the first loop which results in your situation, where a new dataframe is generated for every instance. You need to initialize the dataframe before the first loop or outside the first loop to get a single dataframe.

Here is the corrected code:

```
df_rows = []
# first for loop
for instance in vcenter:
    try:
        c = SmartConnect(host=instance, user=userid, pwd=p, sslContext=s)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
    content = c.content
    obj_ds = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder,[vim.Datastore],True)
    # List for storing single row data
    row = []
    
    # second for loop
    for z in obj_ds.view:
        row.append(instance)
        row.append(z)
        row.append(int(z.summary.capacity/(1024*1024*1024)))
        row.append(int(z.summary.freeSpace/(1024*1024*1024)))
    df_rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(df_rows, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
print(df)
```

Hope this has helped.